Open specific view onContinueUserActivity
I am implementing spotlight search in my CoreData app. Indexing works fine, and when I click on the search result, my app opens in the main view. I have added this to my AppView:
import CoreSpotlight
import SwiftUI

struct AppView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        // main view implementation

        }
        .onContinueUserActivity(CSSearchableItemActionType) { activity in
            continueActivity(activity)
        }
    }

    func continueActivity(_ activity: NSUserActivity) {
       if let id = userActivity.userInfo?[CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier] as? String {
           // open detail view for the selected item
       }
   }
}

I don't want to open the main view but a detail view with the info of the selected item.
How can I do this?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/restoring_your_app_s_state_with_swiftui

This is the solution I came up with. First I get the actual NSManagedObject (an Entry), and then I append it to myNavigationPath.
I hope it is helpful for others.
func continueActivity(_ userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
    if let id = userActivity.userInfo?[CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier] as? String {
        if let entry = coreDataController.entryFromObjectID(id) {
            myNavigationPath = .init()
            myNavigationPath.append(entry)
        }
    }
}

In my CoreDataController:
func entryFromObjectID(_ id: String) -> Entry? {
    if let url = URL(string: id), let objectID = myPersistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: url) {
         if let entry = container.viewContext.object(with: objectID) as? Entry {
            return entry
         }
    }

    return nil
}

